# PHP Pear Mail help

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, pear

this is my code

```
    $from = "Whatever<whatever@gmail.com>";
    $to = "whatever<whatever@hotmail.com>";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "whatever@gmail.com";
    $password = "whatever";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     } else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     }

?>
```

The error i get is : 
Warning: require_once(PEAR.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pedurc5m/php/Mail.php on line 46

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='/home/pedurc5m/php/') in /home/pedurc5m/php/Mail.php on line 46
My shared host web server says that

Location of Your PHP Extension(s) and Application(s)

Path: /home/pedurc5m/php

Why am i getting an error ?
I'm VERY new to PHP,thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

It means that PEAR.php is not in this path /home/pedurc5m/php/

Comment: is it supposed to be there by default ? or could i download it from somewhere.

I installed the PEAR MAIL package from a software package that my web space provider was offering.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have PEAR installed or don't have the Mail module. Look [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) for how to setup PEAR on your host. Once you setup PEAR, install the Mail module and your code should work. (In the linked page scroll down and look for 'PEAR in hosting environments')

Comment: thanks for your reply
I'v installed PEAR Mail. I installed it using my web hosts software package, so i don't think it should be a problem. I can see some new files(PEAR MAIL package) in my PHP directory too

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the full script please? (with your requires and includes?) The way PHP finds dependencies is

1) They are explicitly declared at top of your script - full path to whatever class/function  you need

2) Your php.ini include_path settings - I believe that should be correct in your case.

3) Your custom class loader via __autoload